# How do I get Homebrew on Linux to preserve my PATH when building formulae?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, .profile, linuxbrew

I am trying to use Homebrew on Linux (Ubuntu 20.04) to install Swift Mint. I have installed swiftenv using Homebrew, and swift using swiftenv. In my `.profile`, I have included

```
export SWIFTENV_ROOT=/home/linuxbrew/.swiftenv
if which swiftenv > /dev/null; then eval "$(swiftenv init -)"; fi
```

to put `swift` in my `PATH`. Running `echo $PATH` gives

```
/home/linuxbrew/.swiftenv/shims:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin:/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/sbin:/home/me/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

and `which swift` yields `/home/linuxbrew/.swiftenv/shims/swift`.

However, running `brew install mint` errors with

```
swift build --disable-sandbox -c release --arch arm64 --arch x86_64
make: swift: Command not found
make: *** [Makefile:18: build] Error 127

READ THIS: https://docs.brew.sh/Troubleshooting
```

To explore, I obtain a debug shell after the error with `brew install --debug mint`
In the debug shell, running `echo $PATH` gives

```
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/shims/linux/super:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

and `which swift` turns up nothing.

What am I supposed to do to pass `/home/linuxbrew/.swiftenv/shims` into `brew` so that this package can build?
Ideally, the solution would allow me to run (the swiftenv part of) my `.profile` before building the formula so that I can avoid the possible fragility of swiftenv moving its shims directory.